# Qual è il significato di "se tiene" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il giorno della civetta* ho letto:

> «Non lo so, mio caro, non lo so: io i conti li faccio sempre sul peggio che può venire. Consideriamo dunque che Pizzuco parla: e Mariano è sistemato per le feste. 
>   Ad occhio e croce io dico che in questo momento i carabinieri tentano di saldare l'anello di Pizzuco a quello di Mariano; **se tiene**, i casi sono due: o la catena finisce con Mariano, o Mariano, vecchio com'è, sofferente, comincia a cantare il suo rosario... E in questo caso, mio caro, la catena si allunga si allunga, si allunga tanto che mi ci posso trovare impigliato anch'io, e il ministro, e il padreterno... Un disastro, mio caro, un disastro...».

Non capisco il senso dell'espressione "se tiene" in questo brano. Ho cercato nella voce "tenere" in alcuni dizionari ma, tra le tantissime accezioni che ha questo verbo, non riesco a vedere a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio precedente. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il soggetto di "tiene" è l'anello di Pizzucco saldato a quello di Mariano. Il verbo "tenere", in questo caso, significa che la saldatura rimane, non si rompe. In senso figurato, significa che il collegamento tra i due è valido e la confessione di Pizzucco ha effetto. Se il collegamento è valido, dice Sciascia, o Mariano tace e quindi la catena si interrompe (non si può saldare nessun altro anello) o Mariano racconta a sua volta qualcosa e sarà così possibile aggiungere un anello, poi un altro, poi un altro ancora.